# Process Accessability

Tags: python, file, operation

I am trying to write some information into the file, which is located in
ftp, and this file can be updated by number of people, but if at all i
download a file from the ftp to my local machine, update it and then
upload it back to ftp, and at the same time if some one else downloads
the same file for the modification, then the data will be overwritten.

so is there a way in Python script where i can lock the file, so that
no one updates it until i release the lock

Comment: You want to check whether other processes are currently accessing a file?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use some version control system e.g., `git` (Create a bare git repository on the ftp server, clone it and push/pull from it).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [**fuser**](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/fuser1.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you need to know for debugging purposes or to support a feature in the code but this is the method call to get the pid of the current executing process.

```
import os

print "Process id:",os.getpid()
```

This will simply dump the id to output and you can put other information of interest there so you can follow which is what.

Is this what you are looking for? If not, please clarify and I'll try again.

Comment: actually i want to add just a feature in a code. i only want to check  a file before processing that it is using  by other process or not. if it is i will wait till the process leaved the file, after that i will perform my operation on file.

Comment: ah, ok, I misunderstood. please disregard my answer/response above.